# Create array of json objects from array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array

```
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"];
```

How do I get the array to be a array of objects like so?

```
var nameObjs = [{"name":"bob"},{"name":"joe"},{"name":"jim"}];
```

I've tried doing a loop and adding { and } manually but the loop just ends up getting to big, but I feel like something like JSON.stringify would be the 'correct' way of doing it.

Comment: What do you mean "the loop just ends up getting to [sic] big"? Why don't you share what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"];

var nameObjs = names.map(function(item) {
    return { name: item };
});
```

You can then use `JSON.stringfy` on `nameObjs` if you actually need JSON.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA5xV/1/)

Comment: Damn you, posted while I was finishing typing the last few characters of this exact answer.

Comment: @tenub: Happens to me *all the time*.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
// Get your values however rou want, this is just a example
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"];

//Initiate a empty array that holds the results
var nameObjs = [];

//Loop over input.
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    nameObjs.push({"name": names[i]}); //Pushes a object to the results with a key whose value is the value of the source at the current index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is:

```
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"];
var namesObjs = []
for (var i = 0; i<names.length; i++) {namesObjs.push({name:names[i]})}
```

This is with a loop, but not that big

You make a function to do this:

```
function toObj(arr) {
    obj=[];
    for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {obj.push({name:arr[i]})}
    return obj;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dH6MH/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `names` afterward...

```
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"],
  nameObjs = [];

while (names.length) {
  nameObjs.push({
    'name': names.shift()
  });  
}
```

or even...

```
var names = ["bob", "joe", "jim"],
  n;
for (n in names) {
  names[n] = {'name': names[n]};
}
```